# Using 'kmath' in XeLatex

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, font-encodings

I'm using the Kerkis font family in XeLatex, but math-mode uses the default font. I have installed the OTF font files and it works fine for text when I am specifying it as the main font like this:

```
\setmainfont[
UprightFont = Kerkis,
ItalicFont = KerkisItalics,
SlantedFont = KerkisItalics,
BoldFont = Kerkissb,               
BoldItalicFont = Kerkissbi,        
BoldSlantedFont = Kerkissbi,       
SmallCapsFont = KerkisSmallCaps]   
{Kerkis}
```

I am writing in greek, and when i use the kmath package it messes up the enconding and the document no longer displays correctly. Is there a way to use kmath or at least to have math mode use the kerkis font?

**edit:** This is what i get when i am using kmath:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{kmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\setmainfont[
UprightFont = *,
ItalicFont = *Italics,
SlantedFont = *Italics,
BoldFont = *sb,               
BoldItalicFont = *sbi,
BoldSlantedFont = *sbi,       
SmallCapsFont = *SmallCaps
]{Kerkis}

\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[
UprightFont = *,
ItalicFont = *Italics,
SlantedFont = *Italics,
BoldFont = *sb,               
BoldItalicFont = *sbi,
BoldSlantedFont = *sbi,       
SmallCapsFont = *SmallCaps
]{Kerkis}

\setmainlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

% A lot of document structuring omitted

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \section{Ερώτημα 1}
    % Omitted text
    Όντας πλέον γραμμικό το σύστημα μπορεί να γραφτεί στη μορφή $\dot{x} = Ax+B\upsilon$:
    $$
    \dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 3 \\ -5 & -2\end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\upsilon
    $$
    όπου $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\end{bmatrix}^T$ το διάνυσμα των καταστάσεων και $\dot{x}=\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_1 & \dot{x}_2\end{bmatrix}^T$ το διάνυσμα των παραγώγων τους.
```

**edit 2:** I fixed math-mode not using kerkis, by removing: `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, but the text enconding is still wrong.

Comment: Please, show the code that produces that gibberish. Of course `unicode-math` mustn't be used, because `kmath` doesn't provide a Unicode math font.

Comment: I tried using your own code verbatim, and it still produced garbage. If I uninstall the kerkis from MiKTex Settings, and not use kmath text works fine, but the second I install kmath it installs kerkis and i get the above.

Comment: That's not a minimal example of code. Please, add it: it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no real problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont[
  UprightFont = *,
  ItalicFont = *Italics,
  SlantedFont = *Italics,
  BoldFont = *sb,               
  BoldItalicFont = *sbi,
  BoldSlantedFont = *sbi,       
  SmallCapsFont = *SmallCaps
]{Kerkis}

\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[
  UprightFont = *,
  ItalicFont = *Italics,
  SlantedFont = *Italics,
  BoldFont = *sb,               
  BoldItalicFont = *sbi,
  BoldSlantedFont = *sbi,       
  SmallCapsFont = *SmallCaps
]{Kerkis}

\setmainlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

\begin{document}

Η Αθήνα είναι η πρωτεύουσα και μεγαλύτερη πόλη της Ελλάδας. Είναι 
από τις παλαιότερες πόλεις του κόσμου, με την καταγεγραμμένη
ιστορία της να φθάνει ως το 3.200 π.Χ.
\[
a\sin\varphi=\int_{0}^{\pi} f(\eta)\,d\eta
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's what I get from your example file:

[image]

Comment: I just tried replacing my code with yours, and it gave me the following error: `Option clash for package fontspec. \usepackage`

Comment: I moved the package directives to the top and i got rid of the error, but now the enconding is messed up again. Also the math font remains the default .

Comment: @svart A minimal example for the failure is needed

Comment: How is your setup different than mine? Are you using MikTex? How did you install the Kerkis font?

Comment: @svart No, I'm not with MiKTeX, which is notorious for mixing up, when fonts are concerned. I installed the Kerkis OT fonts long ago, while `kmath` is provided by TeX Live.

Comment: Alright I am going to try TeX Live and I'll report back

Comment: Installing Tex Live fixed the problem! Thanks!